# How to get multiple column's rows value in a single column?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two table **tblCompany** and **tblUser**
Both table contains email id fields, tblCompany contain 3 column as named **contact1Email , contact2Email, contact3Email** and tblUser contain a column named **emailId**. Unique field in both table is companyId. I want to get email of company and user's email those are belongs to that company. all those email ids I want in a single column.
I tried it in basic way using below query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT contact1Email , contact2Email, contact3Email, emailId
FROM fm_company
INNER JOIN fm_users ON fm_company.companyId = fm_users.companyId
WHERE fm_company.companyId =33
```

this gives bellow result as shown in image
[image]

you can see there emailId column contain user's email and contact1Email , contact2Email, contact3Email contain company email.
I want all email in single column as name emailIds. How can it posible using sql query.?

I want a result like

```
|EmailIds         |
|-------------------
|a@a.ll
|-------------------
|asdasdasd@asd.asd
|-------------------
|asdasdasd1@asd.asd
|-------------------
|aaaaa@a.ll
|-------------------
|asd@aswq.km
|-------------------
|aa@asd.ff
|-------------------
```

Comment: Edit your question and provide the desired results that you want.

Comment: Most people here want formatted text, not images.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can  use `concat_ws()` to combine all into a single column:

```
SELECT DISTINCT CONCAT_WS(';', c.contact1Email , c.contact2Email, c.contact3Email, u.emailId) as emailIds
FROM fm_company c INNER JOIN
     fm_users u
     ON c.companyId = u.companyId
WHERE c.companyId = 33;
```

EDIT:

It occurs to me that you want a single email in each row, with multiple rows.  If so:

```
select contact1Email as email
from company c
where c.companyId = 33
union -- on purpose to remove duplicates
select contact2Email as email
from company c
where c.companyId = 33
union
select contact3Email as email
from company c
where c.companyId = 33
union
select u.emailId
from fm_company c join
     fm_users u
     on c.companyId = u.companyId
where c.companyId = 33;
```

Answer (score 1):

**TRY THIS:** According to your question you want to display multiple columns email id in single column so I think you should use `UNION` `OR` `UNION ALL` to achieve the desired output in desired format as below:

```
SELECT DISTINCT contact1Email
FROM fm_company
INNER JOIN fm_users ON fm_company.companyId = fm_users.companyId
WHERE fm_company.companyId =33
UNION
SELECT DISTINCT contact2Email
FROM fm_company
INNER JOIN fm_users ON fm_company.companyId = fm_users.companyId
WHERE fm_company.companyId =33
UNION
SELECT DISTINCT contact3Email
FROM fm_company
INNER JOIN fm_users ON fm_company.companyId = fm_users.companyId
WHERE fm_company.companyId =33
UNION
SELECT DISTINCT emailId
FROM fm_company
INNER JOIN fm_users ON fm_company.companyId = fm_users.companyId
WHERE fm_company.companyId =33
```